# Changing variable names in R based on key in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, variable-names

Suppose I have a dataset in R with variables named `dog` `cat` and `cow`.  Then there are some number of values under each variable (ie. each is =1 if the respondent owns one and =0 if they don't):

```
household_ID   dog   cat   cow
00001          0     1     1
00002          1     0     1
00003          0     0     0
```

Suppose I have another dataset where one column contains my current variables, and another column contains new variable names such that each row contains the new name that should replace the old name:

```
oldname  newname
dog      canine
cat      feline
cow      bovine
```

My goal in this oversimplified example is to replace the variable names of the first dataset using the second dataset.  I'm imagining some kind of loop where you `replace var = newname if var = oldname` but I can't get the syntax right and I'm a little stumped. Here's what I'm hypothetically after:

```
household_ID   canine   feline   bovine
00001          0        1        1
00002          1        0        1
00003          0        0        0
```

Comment: Fixed it. Realized I couldn't use fish when I couldn't think of the word like "canine" or "feline" for "fish". Dumb.

Answer (score 1):

If 'cow' is the 'oldname' third value in second data, we can use `rename_with`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
     rename_with(~ df2$newname, df2$oldname)
```

-output

```
df1
   household_ID canine feline bovine
1            1      0      1      1
2            2      1      0      1
3            3      0      0      0
```

---

Or may use `setnames` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setnames(df1, df2$oldname, df2$newname)
```

#### Update

If the OP's data have columns such as 'dog1', 'dog2', 'cat1', 'cat2' etc and wanted to replace with `canine1`, `canine2` etc, we can use `str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
names(df1new)[-1] <- str_replace_all(names(df1new)[-1], deframe(df2))
```

-output

```
df1new
  household_ID canine1 feline1 bovine1 canine2 feline2
1            1       0       1       1       0       1
2            2       1       0       1       1       0
3            3       0       0       0       0       0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(household_ID = 1:3, dog = c(0L, 1L, 0L), cat = c(1L, 
0L, 0L), cow = c(1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(oldname = c("dog", "cat", "cow"), newname = c("canine", 
"feline", "bovine")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df1new <- structure(list(household_ID = 1:3, dog1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L), cat1 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L), cow1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L), dog2 = c(0, 1, 0), cat2 = c(1, 
0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thats great, thank you. Let me add one more nuance.  Suppose df1 actually contains variables `dog1` `dog2` `cat1` `cow1` `cow2` `cow3`. And we have the same df2. So df2 doesn't contain the old and new variable names with the index at the end, but only the base "dog" "cat" or "cow".  Any thoughts on how to get from there to a place where my new variable names are `canine1` `canine2` `feline1` etc.